# How to JSON parse a ruby string that has interpolated value?

Tags: ruby, json

When I try to parse a ruby string into JSON, the self.id raises an error about an invalid token.

```
JSON.parse "{ 'description' => 'client #{self.id} has been deleted.' }"
```

I tried single quotes around the object, but this results in no interpolation.  How do I get both the interpolation and a successful JSON parse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that even without the interpolated value, your string is invalid JSON.

```
"{ 'description' => 'client has been deleted.' }"
```

The following is valid JSON:

```
'{ "description": "client has been deleted." }'
```

Note the double quotes around the key and value, as well as the colon `:` instead of the hash rocket `=>` which is ruby specific.

Perhaps you are trying to convert a Ruby hash into json?

```
require 'json'
id = 5
x = { 'description' => "client #{id} has been deleted." }.to_json
puts x  # '{ "description": "client 5 has been deleted." }'
```

Comment: I think the poster doesn't know that what he posted isn't really JSON, or JS.  They obviously have a ruby string, and are just trying to evaluate it.

Comment: I was trying to parse JSON, but I accidentally copied and pasted the ruby hashes after I had given up on getting the JSON to work.  This still doesn't work for me.  This is the error I get. JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at '{ "description" : "client #{self.id} has been #{action_past}." , "new_values" => "#{changes || {}}" }'

Comment: `'{ "description" : "client #{self.id} has been #{action_past}." , "new_values" => "#{changes || {}}" }' ` This is still not valid JSON. You have a hash rocket  instead of a colon in there.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you're just trying to run some ruby from a string.  So, assuming self.id is 1:

```
eval "{ 'description' => 'client #{self.id} has been deleted.' }"
```

Would yield:

```
=> {"description"=>"client 1 has been deleted."}
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit dangerous to use "eval"?

Comment: Perhaps, but OPs question is related to a string that includes (effectively) a code block.  I can't see any way of parsing that that doesn't include some kind of eval -- they want to write some kind of custom parser.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use string interpolation within the JSON string, you can escape the double quotes used within the JSON.

For example,

```
id = 1
JSON.parse"{ \"description\": \"client #{id} has been deleted.\" }"
```

yields

```
 => {"description"=>"client 1 has been deleted."}
```